# Field calculator won't let me add numbers from an integer field into a text field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, text, integer

I'm trying to field calculate a text field & add digits to it from a 32 bit integer field, by using the expression `"ID"+"Fiber Capa"` in QGIS 3.28. But the error message

> An error occurred while evaluating the calculation string: Cannot
> convert 'C051-A-' to double

pops up. I'm trying to update the text field so not sure why the message says I'm trying to convert to double.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The error says so, because you are using a `+` operator. This implies you want to do a mathematical calculation; therefore the attempt to convert the string to double. You could force QGIS to not do that, by converting the number to a string in the first place: `"ID"+to_string("Fiber Capa")`.

But more common, if you want to concatenate, just use `||` or the function `concat()` instead: `"ID"||"Fiber Capa"` or `concat("ID","Fiber Capa")`